# Azure PaaS logical server Create time

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

Anyone knows how to get the "logical server" create time? I'm unable to find this in any Azure cmdlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get it from `Activity log`.

[image]

Update:

Activity log is limited to 90 days. Another way you could find Deployments templates in Azure Portal.

[image]

In SQL, you could use following sql query to get creation data.

```
SELECT name, database_id, create_Date, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases
```

Please check this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8b331dff-51ba-400d-9deb-d1ab8a39f4c8/query-to-find-db-creation-date?forum=ssdsgetstarted).

Comment: Thanks @Walter , I think this and actually trying to query the SQL itself and getting the create date of the master user. Querying the log would somehow be hard especially if there are some servers that have been created quite a long time ago and I really wanted to get the created date without logging into the server itself.

Comment: `logical server` Do you mean SQL server, you also could get creation data from Activity log.

Comment: In SQL, maybe you could execute `SELECT name, database_id, create_Date, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases`

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8b331dff-51ba-400d-9deb-d1ab8a39f4c8/query-to-find-db-creation-date?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: Sadly, unable to go via log route since logs is limited to past 90 days. Actually the way I get it via SQL is through `SELECT CAST(create_date as date)
FROM master.sys.sql_logins
WHERE principal_id = 1` but I cannot go through this route as I don't have access to all. I kinda need an external property for this since its the Logical Server creation time that I need.

Comment: @CarlArdiente In your resource group, click `Deployments`, find your sql creation task, you could get the creation data. It could list log more than 90 days. Check https://imgur.com/a/Oc66x

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the deployments, I will look into this and update you once I am able to extract per server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159374/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-carl-ardiente).

Comment: sorry I just got back to work now. Will try to chat you up later but i'll try to look and script it on my end first. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Fine, if you have question, please post here.